# diagonalizability implies existence of an inner product wrt an operator is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Prove that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with respect to which $A$ is normal.

Proof: Suppose there exists an inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with respect to which $A$ is normal. We wish to show that $A$ is diagonalizable which precisely means that $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ has a basis of eigenvectors of $A$. The complex Spectral theorem asserts that an operator $A$ on a complex finite dimensional inner product space $(\mathbb{C}^{n}, \langle, \rangle )$ is normal if and only if $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ has an orthonormal basis, $\mathfrak{B}$, of eigenvectors for $A$, which implies $A$ is diagonalizable.

Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable. Then there exists a basis $\mathfrak{B}$ of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ consisting of eigenvectors for $A$. We can apply the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to this to create an orthonormal basis. I would think the inner product that we must define to make this work has to be some kind of a trick. Perhaps we do a change of basis from this to the standard basis on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. I would benefit from a better approach to this implication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, there is a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ for $\mathbb{C}^n$ consisting of eigenvector of $A$. Define an inner product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by setting $\left<v_i, v_j \right> = \delta_{ij}$ (so we force the basis $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ to be orthonormal) and extending bilinearly. More formally, given $u, w \in \mathbb{C}^n$, represent them with respect to the basis $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ uniquely as $u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i, w = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i v_i$ and define

$$ \left< u, w \right> := \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \overline{w_i}. $$

Check that this indeed defines an inner product. By the theorem you quoted, $A$ will then necessarily be a normal operator with respect to this inner product (since by construction it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors).